# How do I use an array value in a switch statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, switch-statement

I have a spreadsheet with names in column A.  I loop through the names with a switch statement.  However, it does not match the array value.  What Am I doing wrong?  Here's the code:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function switchTest() {
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test Switch");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Test Switch!A2:A").getValues();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
 for(i = 0; i<= lastRow; i++){
   switch(data[0,i]){
    case "John Doe":
      console.log("In John Doe");
      break;
    case "Jane Doe":
      console.log("In Jane Doe");
      break;
      default:
        console.log("Default");
     } 

  }
}
```

`

here's the sheet
[screen shot of Test Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii6Yx.png)

It works if I use an if statement

Comment: In your script, how about modifying `data[0,i]` to `data[i][0]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
function switchTest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Test Switch");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    switch (r[0]) {
      case "John Doe":
        console.log("In John Doe");
      case "Jane Doe":
        console.log("In Jane Doe");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Default");
        break;
    }
  })
}
```